# DEC alpha openvms powerhouse data migration

Tags: openvms

I have been charged with determining the requirements to migrate data from applications running OpenVMS on DEC alpha.  I have no knowledge of openvms or powerhouse, however, I have plenty of experience with linux.  I am able to connect to the server via SSH.

My question is are there any standard tools part of openvms I can use to help me verify the database back end?  get an idea of how many tables, rows of data, etc.?

Comment: The first question would be: What database? Rdb, Oracle, ...? Your question doesn't really belong on SO as it isn't directly related to programming. Have you checked [COGNOiSe](http://www.cognoise.com/index.php)?

Comment: How do I even confirm the database?  Is Rdb the same thing as RMS?  I believe I have seen some references to RMS.

Comment: [Rdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Rdb) was DEC's DB software back in the day, since acquired by Oracle. It is a separately licensed layered product. (The `SHOW LICENSE` DCL command would show a license for it.) [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_Management_Services) is part of the OpenVMS file system which supports fixed- and variable-length records, indexes, ... .

Comment: Where are you trying to migrate to?

Answer (score 1):

What is the goal? Move the (structured) data over for once and for all?
Move application functionality over?
Move ongoing changes over?

You'll have to dig into the system to figure out what it does, what it is build upon. Is there no design guide, an operations play book, backup procedures?

Most likely it is based on RMS (indexed) files. The data file would be names .IDX, .INX, or .DAT or some such, and there would be mane files, one par 'table/object'. The procedures would table about BACKUP, and CONVERT.
There would be a PowerHouse Dictionary from which metadata can be extracted with "qshow generate file" into .ph files.
You may want to look at Attunity (I work there), Connx or Easysoft to use those definitions to provide ODBC or JDBC access to the data from the outside.

Attunity has tools to bulk unload into any target DB with 'one click' once the data definitions are in place, but it is likely too costly for one-time use. 
Still, if the alternative is two months of consulting/coding then a tool may be attractive.

If it is based on RDB, then you would see a few .RDB files,  .RBR and .AIJ files.
There would be .SQL script morcels and operations via "RMU"
Like any other database it would include metadata and has native option for remote ODBC, or (Oracle) OCI access

Hope this helps some,
Hein.